# MakeInstant from Text doesn't work - Argument to MakeInstant should have a different form

Tags: date, app-inventor

I've been playing with MIT AppInventor and attempted to calculate a duration between two dates.

I take date values from two text fields.  Clock.MakeInstant says it's only able to accept dates in MM/DD/YYYY format so I was careful to do that.  Still, when I attempt to feed them into MakeInstant it always pops the same message about being able to only accept MM/DD/YYYY hh:mm:ss or MM/DD/YYYY or hh:mm.  I printed entered text values before passing them to MakeInstant to confirm that they are not somehow corrupted and they are fine -- each just a date in MM/DD/YYYY format.

[image: Code]

[image: Error]

I have no idea what else to try.  As far as I can tell I followed the instructions to the letter.  Any examples on how to pass a date as text to Clock.MakeInstant?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

see this screenshot [image: Calculate the days between dates] source: https://groups.google.com/d/topic/app-inventor-shared-utilities-repository/3bA4wczU9pU/discussion
Taifun

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply.  What I was trying to say is that I was doing that and it doesn't work.  I have added images of the code, date entry, and the final result.

Comment: you should add a plausibility check if both textboxes have the correct format before using MakeInstant, also don't you want to test for "... <= 0"? How does your "then-do" clause look like? I get your error by the way if I click the button without entering a date...

Comment: I got stuck on that first conversion as I thought I was doing something wrong but your answer shows that the code is correct.  After that I added debug output and started disabling parts of the code to see how far I'll get. It turns out this initial duration calculation was fine, the part that fails comes later when I do the same with one of the date fields and another date that I've previously saved in the database.  That second date is in an incorrect format.  Attempting to fix that now but no luck yet -- if I try to save milliseconds and format it later it doesn't work.

Comment: feel free to provide another screenshot... also you might consider asking in the very helpful App Inventor Forum https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/programming-with-app-inventor,  probably someone else already went through this.